# How to use Google Wallet without Ajax rather like Paypal with submitting a form?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, paypal, android-pay

I already use PayPal on my website as it does a php header redirect to submit the page and redirects me to paypal shopping cart. They don't support ajax, if you search for PayPal with ajax you will find cheap looking shopping carts which in the end still do a redirect to paypal which is pretty stupid.

On the other hand Google Wallet doesn't support from my research the old way of doing this with submitting forms to open a Google Wallet shopping cart page..

I want to make them both work without ajax as I want them both to use the same form code.

Anyway to use Google Wallet without this AJAX javascript
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js

How would I be able to do something like this

```
<form method="POST" action="https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/123456789123456" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

This code above is what Google Checkout used before they retired it and forced everyone to use Google Wallet instead.

I understand they are trying to make everything work of AJAX now but they must have some kind of legacy support for the old form method right?

I understand the new Google Wallet requires you to generate some kind of token which is a Base64 encoded with sha256 hash based message authentication code packet which has also has expiration date you set.

https://code.google.com/p/iap-php/source/browse/#git%2Fiap-php%2Fsrc

Example code for Google Wallet: http://iap-php.appspot.com/

But I don't see any way to use this with a website redirect, I went with maybe if I sniff the packet I couldn't figure anything out it's all encrypted probably SSL. I don't understand how [buy.js](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js) works either but I figured out it uses https://sandbox.google.com/checkout which I could probably somehow make into a form? I will have no problem generating the token etc.. as my form first redirects to my own script which sets up the redirection to either paypal cart or google checkout.

Here is how I got my code so far

```
<form method="POST" action="checkout.php" id="buyForm">
   All Fields in here
   submit button value="Paypal"
   submit button value="Google"
</form>
```

my checkout.php uses like

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "PayPal") {
    //Generates all the variables for posting the redirect to PayPal
    $query['cmd'] = '_xclick';
    //Lots of other $query['stuff'] = 'otherstuff'; here
    // Prepare query string
    $query_string = http_build_query($query,'','&');
    header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query_string);
  } else if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Google") {
     //Do the same code as for paypal... with header redirect (no ajax bs)

     //I guessed the below of course it doesn't work
     header('Location: https://sandbox.google.com/checkout?' . $query_string);
  }
?>
```

Comment: IMHO, Google Checkout and Wallet for _Digital Goods_ are different. There is no notion of a "hand off" in the user experience (no redirect to some other web site). A user stays within the context of purchasing digital content at your site (so less friction like shipping == no need for the "extra checkout flow"). It is an "in app" flow - in fact that was the original name of the product (2011) - "In App Payments"...

Comment: Yeah but why did they turn off Google Checkout? they should of kept it.. yes I'm doing this for digital goods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll update this answer later, still working on it seems to work.

Solution using jQuery

I couldn't use jquery `.submit()` function because the form has 2 buttons one has to work normally with paypal the other has to be stopped using this jquery code which focuses on the button for Google Wallet submit.

Here is the API for Google Wallet you place on your HTML/PHP pages.

```
<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
```

```
   //Prevents Button go to Checkout Google from going to checkout.php, because it's ajax
   $('#buyNowGoogle').click(function (event) {
       $("input[name='paymentMethod']").remove(); //so it doesn't use paypal by accident.
       $(this).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="Google"/>');
       $.ajax({
           type: $("#buyForm").attr('method'),
           url: $("#buyForm").attr('action'),
           data: $("#buyForm").serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
               google.payments.inapp.buy({
                   jwt: data,
                   success: function () {
                       $.dialog("show", "Your Order was processed successfully!",
                           "Bought with Google Wallet");
                   },
                   failure: function (result) {
                       $.dialog("show", "Your Order was cancelled!", "Buying with Google Wallet");
                       ga('send', 'event', 'Google Fail', result.response.errorType);
                   }
               });
           },
           error: function (x, t, m) {
               ga('send', 'event', 'Google Wallet Error', x + ' ' + t + ' ' + m);
               if (t === "timeout") {
                   $.dialog("show",
                       "You have timed out, try clicking Buy With Google Wallet again or check your internet, if this problem keeps happening contact us by email or msn at sales@highgamer.com",
                       "Timeout error while buying with Google Wallet");
               } else {
                   $.dialog("show",
                       "You have encountered a Google Wallet error, check your internet, if this problem keeps happening contact us by email or msn at sales@highgamer.com",
                       m);
               }
           }
       });
       event.preventDefault(); //prevent form from getting submitted.
   });
```

checkout.php looks like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['paymentMethod']) && $_POST['paymentMethod'] == "Google") {        
    //JWT class to encode/decode payload into JWT format. */
    include_once "googlecheckout/JWT.php";
    //Get payload of the product.
    include_once "googlecheckout/payload.php";

    $sellerIdentifier = SellerInfo::$issuerId;
    $sellerSecretKey = SellerInfo::$secretKey;

    $payload = new Payload();
    $payload->SetIssuedAt(time());
    $payload->SetExpiration(time()+3600);
    $payload->AddProperty("name", "Piece of Cake");
    $payload->AddProperty("description",
    "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy");
    $payload->AddProperty("price", "10.50");
    $payload->AddProperty("currencyCode", "USD");
    $payload->AddProperty("sellerData",
    "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j");

    // Creating payload of the product.
    $Token = $payload->CreatePayload($sellerIdentifier);

    // Encoding payload into JWT format.
    $jwtToken = JWT::encode($Token, $sellerSecretKey);
   echo $jwtToken;
} else if (isset($_POST['paymentMethod']) && $_POST['paymentMethod'] == "PayPal") {
   //Do paypal code.
}
?>
```

The checkout.php outputs generated token for form paramters and I force Google Wallet ajax button call to automatically display the Google Wallet shopping cart.